# Problem launch spyder

Tags: 20.04, spyder

I encounter the following problem when I want to launch spyder from my ubuntu pc:

```
    TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  scaled(self, int, int, aspectRatioMode: Qt.AspectRatioMode = Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, transformMode: Qt.TransformationMode = Qt.FastTransformation): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
  scaled(self, QSize, aspectRatioMode: Qt.AspectRatioMode = Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, transformMode: Qt.TransformationMode = Qt.FastTransformation): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
```

I have ubuntu 20.04.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer over at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72114520/error-when-starting-spyder-on-ubuntu-22-04/72502984#72502984) and [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/18919#issuecomment-1204098278), there seems to be a mismatch at least with Ubuntu 22.04. The version of Spyder packaged for Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't seem to work with the version of Python packaged for Ubuntu 22.04. I would assume that the same or a similar problem exists with Ubuntu 20.04, too.

A solution would be to install a more recent version of Spyder, according to the sources linked above at least version 5.3.0. Ubuntu 22.04 comes with Spyder in Version 4.2.1+dfsg1-3, Ubuntu 20.04 with version 3.3.6+dfsg1-4build1. You may want to install the more recent version of Spyder in a virtualenv or similar, or to use Anaconda/Miniconda.